# DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler change the retry interval

Tags: java, apache-commons-httpclient

I am using `DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler` class to retry the failure request.

I have tried

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.getParams().
            setParameter(HttpMethodParams.RETRY_HANDLER, 
                         new DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler( 3, false ));
```

This is immediately retrying 3 times. I have not found any option to retry the request after 10 minutes or 1 hour.

How can i set the intervals between retries?

Answer (score 0):

Based on this answer http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.apache.commons.httpclient.DefaultHttpMethodRetryHandler, you can use the following:

```
 client.getParams().
        setParameter(HttpConnectionParams.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 2000);
```

Cheers!